# The name 'MyLibrary' does not exist in the current context

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010

When I try to build a project I have this mistake:

`The name 'F7Utils' does not exist in the current context`

I've got this mistake whenever I try to build my `WPF` project. `F7Utils`, as its name says, is a private library that I created by myself. And I refer it in my project. So, as it's referred, I don't understand what's happening...

This is my structure:

[image]

And this how I call it:

```
String a = F7Utils.Nullable.NullValue.String;
```

And then it launches the error.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error can occur if your library doesn't use `F7Utils` as the namespace for the `Nullable` type.  This can also happen if your types are not `public` within your library.

On a side note, I would recommend not using the same type names as framework types, such as `Nullable`, as this will just cause your code to be less maintainable.

Comment: @Sonhja Are the types (`Nullable`) *public* inside of F7Utils?

Comment: Yes they are. Reed, thanks. It was a  mistake related to the Framework... -_-